# IMU yaw + laser scan + laser geometry = point cloud?

Tags: imu, laser, laserscan, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to use the yaw from my IMU published as [sensor_msgs/Imu](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Imu.html) to turn laser scans into point clouds. My imu_link and laser_link are joined together in my urdf file. I think I need to transform imu_link with the Imu.orientation.z field but I don't know how to!
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10669/imu-yaw-+-laser-scan-+-laser-geometry-=-point-cloud-?/) by [patrick_hammer](https://answers.ros.org/users/465/patrick_hammer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 283 on 2011-07-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need a tf broadcaster, check this tutorial is very easy to understand: [tf broadcaster](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20broadcaster%20%28C%2B%2B%29)
The IMU message publish "orientation" which is a geometry_msgs/Quaternion so, in the node where you do the tf broadcast just add a subscriber to this IMU message, get the orientation, transform it using tf::quaternionMsgToTF(geometry_msgs::Quaternion, tf::Quaternion) and pass it straight to the transform.setRotation(tf::Quaternion)
Take into account you have to choose well your frame_id's, if you have already a tf with the urdf file which joins laser and imu, then you should transform from, for example, "world" to "imu_link".
Resuming you need a node with a subscriber to the IMU message and a tf broadcaster. In this node you have to transform the imu message orientation to a tf::Quaternion and then do the rotation and publish it.

---

Originally posted by [martimorta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69/martimorta/) with karma: 843 on 2011-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1